# ESP32 UART TX slow response rate

Tags: arduino, avr, c, esp32

I`m having issue with UART communication between AVR and ESP32. Issue is with TX response rate.

Here is what I`m sending with AVR, first 2 bytes are command, last 3 are data:

```c
    //command
    Serial2.write(0x01);
    Serial2.write(0x62);
    //data
    Serial2.write(0x69);
    Serial2.write(0x70);
    Serial2.write(0x71);
  
    delayMicroseconds(150);
```

Here is esp side, I`m using RX interrupt to get data form avr and store it into global variable and resuming task when right data/command comes:

```c
static void IRAM_ATTR uart_intr_handle(void *arg)
{
    uint16_t i = 0;
    uint16_t rx_fifo_len = 0;
    rx_fifo_len = UART1.status.rxfifo_cnt; // read number of bytes in UART buffer
    
    while(rx_fifo_len) {
        rxbuf[i++] = UART1.fifo.rw_byte; // read all bytes

        if(rxbuf[i] == 0x01 && rxbuf[i+1] == 0x62) {
            dataBuff[0] = rxbuf[i + 2];
            dataBuff[1] = rxbuf[i + 3];
            dataBuff[2] = rxbuf[i + 4];

            xTaskResumeFromISR(xHandle);
        }

        if(rxbuf[i] == 0x02 && rxbuf[i+1] == 0x63) {
            // xTaskResumeFromISR(xHandle2);
        }

        rx_fifo_len--;
    }

    uart_clear_intr_status(EX_UART_NUM, UART_RXFIFO_FULL_INT_CLR|UART_RXFIFO_TOUT_INT_CLR);
}
```

Here is that task:

```c
void task(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        char writeAddress[6];
        uint16_t tempAddress = dataBuff[1] | (dataBuff[0]<<8);
        uint8_t writeData = dataBuff[2];
        
        sprintf(writeAddress, "%d", tempAddress);
        ESP_LOGE("uart", "Address: %s, %x", writeAddress, writeData);
        
        //not implemented yet, but here will function to store data into esp nvs
        //and after data is stored into nvs, esp will send 0x01 to avr, so it knows that data is stored succesfully 

        uart_write_bytes(EX_UART_NUM, &txDataBuff[1], 1);

        vTaskSuspend(NULL);
    }
}
```

But issue is that is sends out data every 5 miliseconds, not on every packet received:
https://postimg.cc/gXDHxZxX

Here is a closeup of packet:
https://postimg.cc/qg1G02fW

So I`m assuming that it takes 5ms to uart_write_bytes(), because of delay of resuming that function, or because another task is interrupting this task?

How could i increase TX response rate, so it responds to every packet, no like every ~30th one?

Your`e answer will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Some of the code in the `while` loop in your interrupt handler is problematic. You're saving a byte into `rxbuf` using `i` as the index, and immediately post-incrementing `i`, with the `rxbuf[i++] = UART1.fifo.rw_byte;` line. But immediately after that you're again using `i` to index into `rxbuf` to check for values there. You're trying to look at values in `rxbuf` which haven't yet been saved there.

Comment: I also don't think you've considered what really happens when your UART receives data. It's receiving it one byte at a time - so the 1st time your interrupt handler gets called, `UART1.status.rxfifo_cnt` will contain the value `1`. But then inside your `while` loop you're assuming that all the bytes you're expecting to receive have already been received - which is not the case. The only time you'll have more than 1 byte to read is if you disable the interrupt for some period of timer to allow for the RX FIFO to fill up.

Comment: Im more concerned about long waiting time sending data back to avr. So you think of wrong interrupt handler function - that is the cause of 5ms delay?

Comment: The reason it's not replying on every packet is that the errors in your interrupt handler prevent it from calling `xTaskResumeFromISR`. Until you fix those bugs it's not going to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Hmm, but as i understand the interrupt is triggering when 10 bytes are recieved - defined by uart_intr.rxfifo_full_thresh = 10 or uart_intr.rx_timeout_thresh = 10

Comment: uart_intr.rx_timeout_thresh = 10 this one i dont fully understand, that value is in microseconds? If there is nothing in FIFO for 10 microseconds, than it triggers interrupt?

Comment: And also, why does it populate than global dataBuff[0], dataBuff[1] and dataBuff[2] with correct data?